# How generate an ics with hyper link on description using javascript

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I'm trying to generate an .ics file using javascript. I am able to open the ics file but when I try to set an html in the body of the ics file the html is shown like plain text...  Below is the parameter string I trying to use to set the description as html... Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
"BEGIN:VCALENDAR
 VERSION:2.0
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 CLASS:PUBLIC
 DESCRIPTION:
 X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text\/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 08.01.0240.003">
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->

<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>

 <A href="www.google.com" title="TEST">TEST</A></BODY>
</HTML>
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160512T123232
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160512T123232
LOCATION:
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:summary
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR"
```

Comment: I've set this: DESCRIPTION;ALTREP="http://www.example.com/somepath/":<a color="red">This is an example description.</a>
but it is still not working.... please help

Comment: Do you intend to use this .ics file in a calendar client or just show the content of the file using Javascript in a web browser?

Comment: @flechilla I'm going to open it on my outlook client installed on my PC. I was trying to  use something like this also: DESCRIPTION;FMTTYPE=text/html:<p>Hello <b>World</b></p> but it is not working.... is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The iCal spec actually explicitly specifies a way to include HTML in iCal:

- `DESCRIPTION;ALTREP="CID:<part3.msg.970415T083000@host.com>":Project...`
  The "ALTREP" property parameter value might point to a "text/html" content portion.
  [RFC 2445 Section 4.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.2.1) and [RFC 5545 Section 3.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.2.1)
- `DESCRIPTION;ALTREP="http://www.wiz.org":The Fall...`
  [RFC 2445 Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.2), at the very top of page 18

The definition of ALTREP says: "The parameter specifies a URI that points to an alternate representation for a textual property value", so any URI scheme is valid. That means we can also use `data:` URLs in there.

That means there is actually a specced way to store HTML descriptions in iCal.

The following is conforming to the spec:

```
DESCRIPTION;ALTREP="data:text/html;<h1>Some text</h1>":Some text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read [iCalendar Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-13), using the `ALTREP` property parameter you can accomplish so, even including html content. Now when the client take the calendar file, it process the content and take the data that it needs from the different calendar components and properties. So if the client use the `ALTREP` property parameter it might render the content in the html format. I don't know if Outlook render the content following the `ALTREP` param, maybe there is other client that do so. Maybe what you have to looking for is a client that render the content by its `ALTREP`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Do you have any examples using this ALTREP? on wikipedia I found this: X-ALT-DESC - Used to include HTML markup in an event's description. Standard DESCRIPTION tag should contain non-HTML version.  

Here is my ical parameters: 
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
X-ALT-DESC:<p color=red> test</p>
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160516T111818
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160516T111818
LOCATION:
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Testing
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your example:

- FMTTYPE=text/html : no need to escape the slash
- your HTML code is multiline but you are not folding each content line as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1
- some other characters (e.g. true intentional line breaks) may need escaping as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.11

Bottom line:

1. Try to use an existing iCalendar library to generate your content. This will take care of all the escaping for you
2. Do generate some iCalendar sample events using rich text and whatever client you are targeting (Outlook ?) as that should give you a good starting point.